# Смена ImageView через locale

Tags: java, android

Как осуществить смену ImageView после переключения языка приложения?

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DivisionsFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonimi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imi"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/imibuttonpic_ru"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonien"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ien"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ienbuttonpic_ru"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/buttonimi"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonimi" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonfti"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fti"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ftibuttonpic_ru"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonien" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonifkis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ifkis"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ifkisbuttonpic_ru"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonfti" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment

```
    public class DivisionsFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String TAG = "DivisionsFragment";

        View v;
        ImageView imibutton;
        ImageView ifkisbutton;
        ImageView ienbutton;
        ImageView ftibutton;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_divisions, container,false);

            imibutton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonimi);
            imibutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ImiFragment imiFragment = new ImiFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, imiFragment, imiFragment.getTag()).commit();
                }
            });

            ifkisbutton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonifkis);
            ifkisbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    IfkisFragment ifkisFragment = new IfkisFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ifkisFragment, ifkisFragment.getTag()).commit();
                }
            });

            ienbutton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonien);
            ienbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    IenFragment ienFragment = new IenFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ienFragment, ienFragment.getTag()).commit();
                }
            });

            ftibutton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonfti);
            ftibutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FtiFragment ftiFragment = new FtiFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ftiFragment, ftiFragment.getTag()).commit();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locale_text"
        android:layout_width="274dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="@string/set_locale"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locale_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locale_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:tint="@color/svfu_accent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/language_96px"
        android:contentDescription="@string/set_locale" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_en"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
        android:text="@string/english"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_ru"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locale_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ru"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:text="@string/russian"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_en"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locale_text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

SettingsActivity

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings_menu);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            Button ru_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ru);
            ru_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("ru_btn.click");
                    Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
                    changeLocale(locale);
                }
            });

            Button en_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_en);
            en_btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("en_btn.click");
                    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
                    changeLocale(locale);
                }
            });
        }

        private void changeLocale(Locale locale)
        {
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources()
                    .updateConfiguration(configuration,
                            getBaseContext()
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics());
            setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то у вас эти картинки используются для imageView:

```
@drawable/ftibuttonpic_ru
@drawable/imibuttonpic_ru
@drawable/ifkisbuttonpic_ru
```

и если это так, то такое распределение картинок. Вам нужно создать поддиректории в папке `@drawable` которые будут соответствовать коду языка ( `en`,`ru`...), типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше вам нужно расположить там картинки. Этот процесс называется локализацией приложения, и про него можно почитать в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Для того чтобы отловить изменение языка, нужно брать код языка:

```
Locale.getDefault().language
```

этот метод вернет код языка, например:

```
en
```

дальше вы можете брать картинку из drawable директории согласно выбранному языку. На странице настроек было бы неплохо производить запись в настройки приложения выбранный язык, чтобы можно было тащить эти данные отовсюду.

P.S. Вопрос максимально непонятный лично мне кажется)) Если бы вы добавили уточняющей информации то можно было бы на него ответить точнее.